# Passing an int to an Object argument

Tags: java, object, int

A couple of my classmates are having a problem that I'm not able to reproduce, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on their issue.

Our assignment required us to make a method using this signature:

```
public void addElement(int index, Object element) {...}
```

This method is called by a provided (pre-written) driver class with this line:

```
list1.addElement(addIndex, int1);
```

As you may have guessed, `int1` is an int.  This works fine for me, but some people are receiving an error message:

```
"The method addElement(int, Object) in the type LinkedList is not applicable for the  arguments (int, int) "
on list1.addElement(addIndex,int1);
```

I've tried using different IDEs and different versions of JDK, but still can't reproduce the issue.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are they using Java 1.4? Because autoboxing was added in Java 5.

Comment: The one that I've asked is using 1.8.0_25-b18

Comment: Double check the project compliance level.

Comment: Is it possible that Eclipse is checking for errors using a different version of Java than what is ran when they compile and run?

Comment: @AndyDudley `1.8.0_25-b18` looks like a JDK build number, not a Java version. It would be possible to have a Java 8 JDK but still mistakenly be compiling to an earlier version.

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens for people who try this out on JDK prior to Java-5, which is when autoboxing has been introduced. If you switch to a JDK that old, you will see this error. Of course this is when variable argument lists were added, too, so you would see other errors as well.

A way that works in all JDKs is as follows:

```
list1.addElement(addIndex, Integer.valueOf(int1));
```